# hhvm public web server accessing from network

Tags: hhvm

is there a way to access hhvm -m server from network because when i type on browser localhost im able to execute php scripts. Without using apache or nginx is there a way to access hhvm web server from network?

Comment: How about `http://[IP of PC running hhvm][hhvm port]/somefile.php`?

Comment: it's like no web server.

Comment: try hhvm --mode daemon instead

Comment: please note that the built-in HHVM server support has been discontinued. Even though HHVM 2.4.1 (the latest release as of this writing) has the built-in webserver, it is recommended to use HHVM with Apache/Nginx in FastCGI mode